# Margin on Master View Controller on iPhone only

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller

I have created a Master/Detail app not using the Apple Default's Template but by simply clearing the storyboard and dragging a split view controller to there.

I select the split view controller and configure it like this:

[image]

The table view controller cell inside the master has only one image view that is 240x180 points.

This image view is configured to have the Content View width and height and be centered.

When I run this project this is how I see the master view controller

**On the iPad**

[image]

**On the iPhone**

[image]

for some reason on the iPhone version the image is not filling the whole cell and is shifted to the right.

This red band is the color when the cell is selected.

Comment: I don't have an answer but I find "Debug->View Debugging->Capture View Hierarchy" very useful as a way to figure out this kind of problem.  It often helps to know runtime frames and constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I love how these APIs do not work consistently across devices.

The same Table View Controller, the same project, shows differently on iPhone and iPad.

The red rectangle is the selected background view, that I have set to red, so when the cell is selected a red rectangle shows around. The problem is that there is an old iOS bug that makes the selection background view to cover the cell content partially.

Apparently the bug happens on the iPhone, but not the iPad.

To solve the problem, turn OFF this `Insets To Safe Area` on the `Size Inspector` of the Table View. This is turned on by default when you create the table.

[image]